# After update of Android Studio 3.6 & Gradle to 3.5.0 unable to run project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-3.6

Everything was working smoothly but after update of Android Stdio 3.6 & Gradle to 3.5.0, Project is not building,
Getting bellow errors

```
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource compilation failed
     C:\Users\Amin\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\c1ea7b9f1e5ec36cfafa4328570d20ad\constraintlayout-2.0.0-beta2\res\values\values.xml:321:5-600: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/pivotX' with config ''.

     C:\Users\Amin\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\c1ea7b9f1e5ec36cfafa4328570d20ad\constraintlayout-2.0.0-beta2\res\values\values.xml:321:5-600: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.

     C:\Users\Amin\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\c1ea7b9f1e5ec36cfafa4328570d20ad\constraintlayout-2.0.0-beta2\res\values\values.xml:321:5-600: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/pivotY' with config ''.
```

Here is gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Comment: just do clean and rebuild project

Comment: do file -> Invalidate Caches and restart

Comment: tried this also, still no luck :(

Comment: `Invalidate cashes / Resart` from file menu. that worked for me

Comment: try upgrade the gradle latest version

Comment: gradle is also up to date

Comment: add this line to gradle.properties: org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally..
I have solved the problem..
I observed error was in constraintlayout as per logcat and observed the constraintlayout version which was alpha
I downgrade the version to `implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'`
and the issue got fixed.

Comment: I have the same error and weirdly enough my error is at res/values/strings.xml

Comment: @Pavlos  did u fix it ?
If yes then would mind explaining me the reason please ?
I am also facing the exact same error during release build.

Comment: @Noman Hope you can fix this issue. I don't have a lot of confidence in those old Android libraries. I suggest removing the line where the code is showing you an error and trying again. One option is to remove libraries that show the problem

Answer (score 2):

Try changing in gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone that tried to do so with `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2` and `Gradle Version 5.4.1` the fix is the same - make sure you are working with

```
androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3
```

when using `3.5.0` and up without `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3` - the UI will be blank (inflate exception) for any view that is extending `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: Relieved (or should that be depressed?) to know there are just as many bugs in Android Studio as in Visual Studio ..