# android instrument fails dexing.DexWorkAction

Tags: android, gradle

I am running connectedAndroidTest but I got

```
 Execution failed for task ':app:dexBuilderDebugAndroidTest'.
    > There were multiple failures while executing work items
       > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.dexing.DexWorkAction
          > Failed to process: C:\Users\benod\Desktop\beno-androidxx\app\build\intermediates\transforms\FirebasePerformancePlugin\androidTest\debug\18.jar
       > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.dexing.DexWorkAction
          > Failed to process: C:\Users\benod\Desktop\beno-androidxx\app\build\intermediates\transforms\FirebasePerformancePlugin\androidTest\debug\18.jar
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After update of Android Studio 3.6 & Gradle to 3.5.0 unable to run project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57852877/after-update-of-android-studio-3-6-gradle-to-3-5-0-unable-to-run-project)

Comment: @Dinu no it does it , the same error

Comment: @Dinu and they are not the same  \FirebasePerformancePlugin but constraintlayout-2.0.0-beta2

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was not exactly as yours, but DexWorkAction aswell

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexBuilderStagingDebugAndroidTest'.
> There were multiple failures while executing work items
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.dexing.DexWorkAction
      > Failed to process: /Users/me/projects/project/app/build/intermediates/asm_instrumented_project_classes/stagingDebugAndroidTest
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.dexing.DexWorkAction
```

I had to upgrade two dependencies: dagger hilt and androidx.navigation. After syncing the project again, the error was gone. Even if I downgrade again, the error is gone. It seems this updated something internally that stopped failing

```
    navigation_version = "2.5.3" // was 2.5.1
    dagger_hilt_version = "2.44.2" // was 2.43.2

    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigation_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigation_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$navigation_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$navigation_version"

    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$dagger_hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$dagger_hilt_version"
    testImplementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:$dagger_hilt_version"
    kaptTest "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$dagger_hilt_version"
    androidTestImplementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:$dagger_hilt_version"
    kaptAndroidTest "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$dagger_hilt_version"
```