# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'

Tags: android-studio, compiler-errors

I am getting this error while running my app.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.1.3/constraint-layout-1.1.3.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.3.1/appcompat-v7-25.3.1.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/25.3.1/support-v4-25.3.1.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.android.support:design:25.3.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design/25.3.1/design-25.3.1.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

Answer (score 35):

I already had the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion on version number 30.
I added to `build.repositories` `jcenter()` and to `allprojects.repositories` `jcenter()`, after that I build the react-native app and it works fine.

My build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()

        
        maven {
            // All of the Detox artifacts are provided via the npm module
            url("$rootDir/../../../node_modules/detox/Detox-android")
        }
        

    }
}
```

Comment: This helped me when I upgraded my react native version from 0.63.4 to 0.65.1. Thank you.

Comment: this saved my day, thanks. this is happening while switching react native versions

Comment: I had to add jcenter() to android/repositories.gradle AND also android/app/repositories.gradle

Comment: In my case I had to add mavenCentral() as I already had jcenter(). Adding mavenCentral() fixed it for me.

Answer (score 29):

For our Flutter Project:
Navigate to app-level build.gradle file.
Change compileSdkVersion from 30 to 31
and Change targetSdkVersion from 30 to 31

Comment: for react native works too!

Comment: To piggy back on this answer, you may face a new error regarding Kotlin after doing this. To fix that change the `ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'` to `ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'` in `android/build.gradle`

Answer (score 11):

This problem is for sdk and jdk version conflict. First you can run:

```
npx react-native doctor
```

After running this command, if you get an error or warning, press "**e**", "**w"** or "**f**" to fix the problem and download the correct version.
I usually use compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion in version #30.
You can change the **sdkVersion** to **30** or **31**

Answer (score 9):

In my case i opened `build.gradle` and updated all libraries to the latest one just like below
[image]

Answer (score 6):

**Update 2021.07**

I just had to change the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` in my build.gradle file. (YourApp\android\build.gradle).

 
`compileSdkVersion` from **29** to **30** 
`targetSdkVersion` from **29** to **30**

after this change, it started to run.

Credit: https://exerror.com/solved-execution-failed-for-task-appcheckdebugaarmetadata/

Comment: It worked for me with `31`.

Answer (score 2):

It happened out of blue with my app one morning without any recent changes - I double checked with Git. The app was working yesterday without any issue. Inside android/app/build.gradle file, changing this one:

```
compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
```

to this one solved the issue:

```
compileSdkVersion 32
targetSdkVersion 32
```

Answer (score 2):

If you get this on Mac while trying to run an Expo Android app, try restarting your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using newer version of Android Studio and your implementation is missing or using deprecated libraries. Otherwise, you could try the following implementation in your `build.gradle (Module: app)` files:

```
  dependencies {
  def appcompat_version = "1.2.0"
    // ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material: 1.2.1'
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompat_version"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:$appcompat_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"
    // ...
  }
```

Comment: I have the same issue. this solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: I solved this issue right now! I just tried with change proxy in this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63157065/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle4-0-1-or-4-0-0/63235324#63235324  that worked for me. try with that.

Answer (score 0):

This error ***"Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath"*** is due to a network failure

It is because Android studio doesn't have full access to internet connection which is caused by another application controlling your proxy. E.g Charles Proxy.

**Solution:**

1. Stop/Close any proxy application on your computer.
2. Rebuild the project

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but somehow my **gradle offline mode** was turned on after android studio 4.1.1 update and this caused the problem. make sure that that thing is **not** turned on!

Answer (score 0):

android>build.gradle

!Check versions properly

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "17.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        ...
    }
    dependencies {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: hello @Rajendra, thank you for contributing to Stackoverflow.  Please provide explanations in your answers. Kindly check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer on how to provide a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

reactnative/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/react-native-reanimated-6*.aar.
Just go to the above path and copy the files and rename what is required, For example, if the problem is not finding 66.aar copy & paste the previous main aar file and hermen aar file in the path and rename it with 66

Answer (score 0):

maybe you didnt install one module correctly

check all module installing documentation

I found that I installed react-native-reanimated incorrectly
and after going throught documentation
https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation

the error was fixed

Answer (score 0):

just add these lines to *android\app\build.gradle*

```
android {
compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
.........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jcenter shut down today. This fixed the problem in my case

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888"
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        // jcenter() <- comment this one
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        maven {
          url "https://sdk.smartlook.com/android/release"
        }

        google()
        // jcenter() <- comment this one
        gradlePluginPortal() // <- and replace it for this one
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Credit to [mchan822's answer](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35136#issuecomment-1297170644)

Comment: You're right, sorry. 
And done !

Comment: Done! Is it ok like this ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got below error

Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.6.1' requires libraries and applications that
depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
Android APIs.

```
build.gradle file content as
    compileSdk 32
    targetSdk 32

dependencies {
   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
   implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
```

}

I changed the compileSdk and targetSdk as 33 and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

on this route: `android -> build.gradle`
add this part `androidXBrowser = "1.5.0"`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        // ...
        androidXBrowser = "1.5.0"
```

[resource1](https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser/issues/423)
[resource2](https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser/issues/423)

this solved my problem

Answer (score -1):

### Mostly this happens on your 1st time running of project /or running in a new device ,
Fix

1. Make sure you have proper internet connection
2. If not fixed then trun of auto detect setting in proxi setting of your pc

Answer (score -1):

I think first you run create apk file cmd and then run build cmd.
problem solved.

Answer (score -2):

for me disabling proxy in windows setting worked

[image: proxy]