# Could not find com.tom_roush:pdfbox-android:1.8.10.0. Required by: project :react-native-html-to-pdf

Tags: react-native

Could not find com.tom_roush:pdfbox-android:1.8.10.0.
Required by:
project :react-native-html-to-pdf
Search in build.gradle files

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This response https://stackoverflow.com/a/68633805/14012034 worked fine to me and solved the problem, particulary adding jcenter()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Install the previous version of this library,may be solve this error.
visit below link
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-html-to-pdf/v/0.9.1