# React-Native: cant't build app with react-native-track-player

Tags: react-native, react-native-track-player

**Problem:**

I **can** build the React Native App `npx react-native run-android`
but when I install react-native-track-player `yarn add react-native-track-player`
it **fails** to build.

**What I have tried:**

`npm i react-native-track-player`(it can't be installed I don't know why?(ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree))

**System:**
Ubuntu and i have not installed Watchman

**Error:**

$ npx react-native run-android

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 898 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.

- daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
- daemon started successfully
  info Launching emulator...
  info Successfully launched emulator.
  info Installing the app...
  Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED
> 8 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 4 up-to-date
> Warning: Mapping new ns schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.11.4.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/android/exoplayer/exoplayer-core/2.11.4/exoplayer-core-2.11.4.pom
> - file:/home/maxim/.m2/repository/com/google/android/exoplayer/exoplayer-core/2.11.4/exoplayer-core-2.11.4.pom
> - file:/home/maxim/Desktop/Development/MusicApp/node_modules/react-native/android/com/google/android/exoplayer/exoplayer-core/2.11.4/exoplayer-core-2.11.4.pom
> - file:/home/maxim/Desktop/Development/MusicApp/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/google/android/exoplayer/exoplayer-core/2.11.4/exoplayer-core-2.11.4.pom
> - dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/exoplayer/exoplayer-core/2.11.4/exoplayer-core-2.11.4.pom
> - [www.jitpack.io/com/google/android/exoplayer/exoplayer-core/2.11.4/exoplayer-core-2.11.4.pom](http://www.jitpack.io/com/google/android/exoplayer/exoplayer-core/2.11.4/exoplayer-core-2.11.4.pom)
> Required by:
> project :app > project :react-native-track-player

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Warning: Mapping new ns schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.11.4.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/android/exoplayer/exoplayer-core/2.11.4/exoplayer-core-2.11.4.pom
> - file:/home/maxim/.m2/repository/com/google/android/exoplayer/exoplayer-core/2.11.4/exoplayer-core-2.11.4.pom
> - file:/home/maxim/Desktop/Development/MusicApp/node_modules/react-native/android/com/google/android/exoplayer/exoplayer-core/2.11.4/exoplayer-core-2.11.4.pom
> - file:/home/maxim/Desktop/Development/MusicApp/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/google/android/exoplayer/exoplayer-core/2.11.4/exoplayer-core-2.11.4.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/exoplayer/exoplayer-core/2.11.4/exoplayer-core-2.11.4.pom
> - https://www.jitpack.io/com/google/android/exoplayer/exoplayer-core/2.11.4/exoplayer-core-2.11.4.pom
> Required by:
> project :app > project :react-native-track-player

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s

```
at makeError (/home/maxim/Desktop/Development/MusicApp/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
at /home/maxim/Desktop/Development/MusicApp/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (/home/maxim/Desktop/Development/MusicApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:106:5)
at async Command.handleAction (/home/maxim/Desktop/Development/MusicApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:192:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Comment: The answer which fixed my Problem was the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68633805/13960172

Answer (score 1):

As jCenter was removed from react-native v0.65+ and no longer allows package updates, all packages should be obtained from mavenCentral. Thus, I would recommend defining the package such that other dependencies are no longer fetched from jCenter. So it is better to include jCenter dependent modules/groups to `android/build.gradle` like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        jcenter() {
            content {
                includeGroup("com.google.android.exoplayer")
            }
        }
        ...

    }
}
```