# React Native - "Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'."

Tags: react-native

So someone posted the same question here [Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64521804/execution-failed-for-task-appcheckdebugaarmetadata). I tried all the solutions suggested, but also my build gradle versioning wasn't the same as theirs. Mine starts at `31` then I changed it to `30`. Not really sure how to fix this most solutions suggest changing the build.gradle, but that's not working. I might try uninstalling NPM and reinstalling then reinstalling all dependencies.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 57s
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
```

build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Comment: As far I can see you are trying to compile your Android app with Gradle. Could you add the` --stacktrace` option to your command for debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add google's `maven` repository into the `allprojects.repositories` like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } // ---------------> added here        

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Try to clean up the project by running `./gradlew clean` command in your android directory and try to **build** or just **run-android**.