# Failed to transform react-native-reanimated-66-jsc.aar

Tags: android, react-native

```
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
108 actionable tasks: 78 executed, 30 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform react-native-reanimated-66-hermes.aar (project :react-native-reanimated) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /Users/jinseokkim/Desktop/프로젝트/my-app/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/react-native-reanimated-66-hermes.aar.
         > Check failed.


"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.66.3",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.0",
```

I'm using the m1 macbook air, but the Android build continues to fail for the same reason as above.

I ask for your advice on what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I think one the following will give you the solution

1. [add jcenter() in buildscript.repositories and allprojects.repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68633805/10657559)
2. [[Solved] Execution failed for task ‘:app:checkDebugAarMetadata’](https://exerror.com/solved-execution-failed-for-task-appcheckdebugaarmetadata/)