# I get error when running my app on android emulator

Tags: flutter, dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Multiple task action failures occurred:
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04.
> AAR metadata file: /Users/imadedevakertiwijaya/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/ebc79c1115e8e75fdf704de6d51ac041/transformed/jetified-window-java-1.0.0-beta04/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta04.
> AAR metadata file: /Users/imadedevakertiwijaya/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/06466bed052bf059256eddf036f755d6/transformed/jetified-window-1.0.0-beta04/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64521804/10157127) will answer

Comment: Update``build.gradle`` (app/module level) -> ``compileSdk`` to ``31`` or higher