# Ionic Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Below error occurred while running command ionic cordova build android. But when I check the location mentioned in the error, the file exists still getting this error.

> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find :tbxml-android:.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - file:/S:/Developer/Projects/driver-app/platforms/android/app/src/main/libs/tbxml-android.aar
> - file:/S:/Developer/Projects/driver-app/platforms/android/app/libs/tbxml-android.aar
> - file:/S:/Developer/Projects/driver-app/platforms/android/libs/tbxml-android.aar
> Required by:
> project :app

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: What did you do before the error occurred? Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64521804/execution-failed-for-task-appcheckdebugaarmetadata

Comment: I have removed node modules and install it again

Comment: did you delete your package-lock.json? or yarn-lock.json? Could be that you installed newer dependencies