# Error: Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'

Tags: flutter, compiler-errors, build-error

I have been trying to fix this exception. I have tried this StackOverflow solution:
[Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64521804/execution-failed-for-task-appcheckdebugaarmetadata) I have tried changing the  `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to version 30 and then 31, but the same exception is thrown. I also tried adding `jcenter()` and nothing changed. Not really sure what to do from here. Error showed up after I came back to some code after a while, no changes were made. The error just started to be thrown when I tried to build.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find any matches for com.transistorsoft:tsbackgroundfetch:+ as no versions of com.transistorsoft:tsbackgroundfetch are available.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://jitpack.io/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/maven-metadata.xml
       - file:/C:/Users/Telaeris/Documents/flutter_dev/flutter_projects/emergency_tracker_app/android/app/libs/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/maven-metadata.xml
     Required by:
         project :app > project :background_fetch

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
```

Comment: I have gotten suggestions to downgrade your Gradle version, but I'm not sure if that is a good idea or what version would make my code work.