# Error while downloading artifacts from internet

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

I upgraded from flutter 1.22.6 to 2.2, when I tried to run the default counter app, I ran into this error. I have tried downgrading my Gradle version and also upgrading it, still didn't fix it.

I also tried the solution from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61986128/gradle-threw-an-error-while-downloading-artifacts-from-the-network-exception) and it didn't work

**Here is the console output:**

```
 Launching lib\main.dart on SM G925F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: please remove the picture ... add the actual text instead

Comment: seems the issue with downloading gradle. Make sure there are no issues with the internet connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by downloading `gradle 7.0` manually and also `build tools 29.0`