# I am getting the following error While adding cloud firestore to my flutter app

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle, google-cloud-firestore

Here is the error I'm getting:

Launching lib\main.dart on RMX2189 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':cloud_firestore'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':cloud_firestore:classpath'.
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.32.
> Required by:
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools:repository:30.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:7.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:30.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-model:30.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto:30.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.build:builder-model:7.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:7.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.2 > com.android.tools:common:30.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:30.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:30.0.2
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.32.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.4.32/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.4.32.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.4.32/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.4.32.pom'.
> > Remote host terminated the handshake
> Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-core:1.21.1.
> Required by:
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.0.2
> > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-core:1.21.1.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-core/1.21.1/grpc-core-1.21.1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-core/1.21.1/grpc-core-1.21.1.pom'.
> > Remote host terminated the handshake
> Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-netty:1.21.1.
> Required by:
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.0.2
> > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-netty:1.21.1.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-netty/1.21.1/grpc-netty-1.21.1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-netty/1.21.1/grpc-netty-1.21.1.pom'.
> > Remote host terminated the handshake
> Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.21.1.
> Required by:
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.0.2
> > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.21.1.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-protobuf/1.21.1/grpc-protobuf-1.21.1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-protobuf/1.21.1/grpc-protobuf-1.21.1.pom'.
> > Remote host terminated the handshake
> Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.21.1.
> Required by:
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.0.2
> > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.21.1.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-stub/1.21.1/grpc-stub-1.21.1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-stub/1.21.1/grpc-stub-1.21.1.pom'.
> > Remote host terminated the handshake
> Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre.
> Required by:
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:7.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:30.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:30.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:7.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.6.0
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:7.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.2 > com.android.tools:common:30.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:30.0.2
> > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/30.1-jre/guava-30.1-jre.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/30.1-jre/guava-30.1-jre.pom'.
> > Remote host terminated the handshake
> Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.20.
> Required by:
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools:sdklib:30.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools:repository:30.0.2
> > Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.20.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.20/commons-compress-1.20.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.20/commons-compress-1.20.pom'.
> > Remote host terminated the handshake
> Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre.
> Required by:
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.10.0
> > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/30.1-jre/guava-30.1-jre.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/30.1-jre/guava-30.1-jre.pom'.
> > Remote host terminated the handshake
> Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre.
> Required by:
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools:repository:30.0.2 > com.google.jimfs:jimfs:1.1
> > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/30.1-jre/guava-30.1-jre.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/30.1-jre/guava-30.1-jre.pom'.
> > Remote host terminated the handshake
> Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre.
> Required by:
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:7.0.2
> > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/30.1-jre/guava-30.1-jre.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/30.1-jre/guava-30.1-jre.pom'.
> > Remote host terminated the handshake
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':cloud_firestore' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':firebase_core'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':cloud_firestore' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 29s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':cloud_firestore'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':cloud_firestore:classpath'.
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.32.
> Required by:
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools:repository:30.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:7.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:30.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-model:30.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto:30.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.build:builder-model:7.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:7.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.2 > com.android.tools:common:30.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:30.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:30.0.2
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.32.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.4.32/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.4.32.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.4.32/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.4.32.pom'.
> > Remote host terminated the handshake
> Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-core:1.21.1.
> Required by:
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.0.2
> > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-core:1.21.1.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-core/1.21.1/grpc-core-1.21.1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-core/1.21.1/grpc-core-1.21.1.pom'.
> > Remote host terminated the handshake
> Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-netty:1.21.1.
> Required by:
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.0.2
> > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-netty:1.21.1.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-netty/1.21.1/grpc-netty-1.21.1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-netty/1.21.1/grpc-netty-1.21.1.pom'.
> > Remote host terminated the handshake
> Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.21.1.
> Required by:
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.0.2
> > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.21.1.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-protobuf/1.21.1/grpc-protobuf-1.21.1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-protobuf/1.21.1/grpc-protobuf-1.21.1.pom'.
> > Remote host terminated the handshake
> Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.21.1.
> Required by:
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.0.2
> > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.21.1.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-stub/1.21.1/grpc-stub-1.21.1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-stub/1.21.1/grpc-stub-1.21.1.pom'.
> > Remote host terminated the handshake
> Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre.
> Required by:
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:7.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:30.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:30.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:7.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.6.0
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:7.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.2 > com.android.tools:common:30.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:30.0.2
> > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/30.1-jre/guava-30.1-jre.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/30.1-jre/guava-30.1-jre.pom'.
> > Remote host terminated the handshake
> Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.20.
> Required by:
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools:sdklib:30.0.2
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools:repository:30.0.2
> > Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.20.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.20/commons-compress-1.20.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.20/commons-compress-1.20.pom'.
> > Remote host terminated the handshake
> Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre.
> Required by:
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.10.0
> > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/30.1-jre/guava-30.1-jre.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/30.1-jre/guava-30.1-jre.pom'.
> > Remote host terminated the handshake
> Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre.
> Required by:
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools:repository:30.0.2 > com.google.jimfs:jimfs:1.1
> > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/30.1-jre/guava-30.1-jre.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/30.1-jre/guava-30.1-jre.pom'.
> > Remote host terminated the handshake
> Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre.
> Required by:
> project :cloud_firestore > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.2 > com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:7.0.2
> > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/30.1-jre/guava-30.1-jre.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/30.1-jre/guava-30.1-jre.pom'.
> > Remote host terminated the handshake
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':cloud_firestore' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':firebase_core'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':cloud_firestore' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 24s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: > This might help you!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61986128/gradle-threw-an-error-while-downloading-artifacts-from-the-network-exception

Comment: this doesn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63187554/13049288 done this??