# Am encountering problem in running my first flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZ18k.png)
am running flutter on android studio have finalize all plugins and android emulator, I was trying to run my first app and encounter the error above in the snippet. what should I try to debug this problem help please

Comment: kinda similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61986128/gradle-threw-an-error-while-downloading-artifacts-from-the-network-exception)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like error could be related to network issues.
i have had similar problem and i fix it by trying different dns.
Check Network Connectivity, Use a Different DNS, Use a VPN, Restart Android Studio and Invalidate Caches: You can do this by selecting "File" > "Invalidate Caches / Restart" from the Android Studio menu.