# React Native: "A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade"

Tags: react-native, gradle

I created a new react native project and ran `react-native run-android`.

However, I am getting this error:

`A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade`

Here's the screenshot:
[image: error 1]

Here's my `android/build.gradle`:

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

**I am new with react native and this is a new project so any help will be appreciated.**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57606462/a-failure-occurred-while-executing-com-android-build-gradle-internal-tasks

Comment: @Hend El-Sahli Apparently none of the solutions helped and I am still getting the error.

Comment: Did you get this issue only in this specific project? I mean try creating a new project, to see if it has to do with your RN-installation

Comment: Yeah I created another new React Native project and faced the same issue. At first it says it's missing `android.jar` which I added manually to its designated folder. And after that I get this problem which I have posted here.

Comment: Then It's an installation issue ... I guess it's not the best way to resolve this issue by **copying the missing android.jar file** ... The error indicates that **You have Android API not installed ... or partially installed** ...From your Android-Studio > Configure > Sdk Manager --> check installed api-levels and make sure API Level-29 is installed ... and make sure **buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2** is installed OR set buildToolsVersion to the once installed in your device

Comment: Thank you so much! I installed the Level-29 and it solved the issue.

Comment: Happy coding...!

Answer (score 1):

**Solution-1:** The problem was resolved by deleting and re-creating the AVD (Android Virtual Device) file. The AVD can be deleted from Android Studio. It is usually saved at `C:\Users\<userName>\.android\avd`

Most likely, you also need to execute the following commands.

```
cd <project_filder> 
cd android
gradlew clean
```

In case you did not notice the comments on the question (above), please check them out. They include more suggestions, which might be relevant to the problem.

1st Update:

**Solution-2:** In some other instance, in addition to deleting and re-creating the AVD, I had to do the following steps.

```
REM 1. Removing cache files
rd %localappdata%\Temp\metro-cache /s /q 
del %localappdata%\Temp\haste-map*

REM 2. Cleaning Gradle files
cd <project_filder> 
cd android & gradlew clean & cd .. 

REM 3. Deleting node_modules
rd node_modules /q /s 

REM 4. Cleaning npm cache
npm cache clean --force 

REM 5. Re-installing npm modules
npm install
```

2nd Update:

**Solution-3:** In a 3rd instance, I had to add the following line in the file `<proj-folder>/android/gradle.properties`

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
```

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting I encountered this in a native (Kotlin) Android project.
For me this was caused by having densities specified in my `resConfigs`:

```
build.grade (:app)

developLint {
    dimension "version"
    resConfigs "en",  "he-rIL", "iw-rIL", "xxhdpi"
}
```

(Note the `"xxhdpi"` above)

Removing the density solved the problem.