# react native android build fails Error: while merging dex archives

Tags: android, react-native

Every time I try to build an Android app it fails because of this error:
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
> Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
> Type com.horcrux.svg.Brush$BrushType is defined multiple times:

anyone can help, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57606462/a-failure-occurred-while-executing-com-android-build-gradle-internal-tasks)

Comment: @HassanKandil unfortunately, no

Comment: Tried cleaning build folder ?

Comment: @HassanKandil yeah I did

Comment: try adding this to app/build.gradle:

android {
    defaultConfig {
       multiDexEnabled true
    }
like this one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46591042/9820315

Comment: @HassanKandil, already did, that's why I'm asking nothing is working, I think it's caused because of react-native-svg and I can't remove it

Comment: So after adding react-native-svg this error happened ?

Comment: @HassanKandil yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230472/discussion-between-hassan-kandil-and-dalia-abu-ghosh).