# How to fix : Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: android, gradle

I'm currently working with Cordova CLI along with Android cmdline-tools, and I'm getting this error when I run cordova build to generate apk.

> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

> Android resource linking failed
> /home/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/1723263284390e5d17b6b8ac539aa999/core-1.7.0/res/values/values.xml:105:5-114:25: AAPT:

> error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.

A couple of days ago was working perfectly but I just can't spot the issue.
What's happening ?

I'm still troubleshooting with this.

Any help is hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is in values.xml file where you have defined android:attr/lStar .
the resource directory is not able to find resource with the same so that the resource can not be found.
You can use this example for further reference.

[A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57606462/a-failure-occurred-while-executing-com-android-build-gradle-internal-tasks)