# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. on flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Hi everyone when I try to run my flutter app on web or windows its work fine But on android I have this error , Even if I create a new project ,So any on can help me please .

[image: 1]

Error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:desugarDebugFileDependencies'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexFileDependenciesTask$DexFileDependenciesWorkerAction
   > zip END header not found

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 33s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: maybe its related to multidex issues? try to check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57606462/a-failure-occurred-while-executing-com-android-build-gradle-internal-tasks

Comment: Try to update all Dependencies and also `flutter`

Answer (score 0):

Add multiDexEnabled in your app/build.gradle
like this

```
defaultConfig {
...

multiDexEnabled true }
```

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work .