# A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I'm getting this error while building my program

```
Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
```

I tried what was on the internet about the error but it didn't work

Comment: Please mention the approaches that you took as well in your question

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace, this could be many things.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution-1

- Try invalidate Caches & Restart

#### Solution-2

In gradle.app file, add these two lines, if didn't and rebuild the project

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

And

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't really figure out the actual problem by this short piece of the stacktrace but a similair problem was answered here: [Old stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57607026/5920608)

The guy fixed it by increasing the jvm args size
add this in your gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
```