# Out of memory. Java heap space after update android studio Eel

Tags: java, android-studio, heap-memory

here is gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
org.gradle.unsafe.configuration-cache=true
```

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue and tried this solution and that worked.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59777137/5706602

Comment: Hi @MertAdsay thanks for your answer, I just optimize my code and reinstalled AS worked for me